# Increase Memory Limit for Cloud Function (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am aware of how to increase the memory limit for a regular Cloud Function. But I can't find any documentation on how to do so for a Cloud Function managed by Firebase.

Comment: the accepted answer is out of date - the correct answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653948/1205871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same procedure - go to the Cloud console and find your project there.  Firebase projects are also Cloud projects.

It's important to realize that it's all just "Cloud Functions" behind the scenes.  There is nothing significant that makes Cloud Functions deployed by the Firebase CLI any different than other Cloud Functions, other than the fact that you used different SDKs and tooling.

The Firebase team is working on ways to make functions configuration more natural for functions deployed by the Firebase CLI.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. My concern was that the configuration might be overwritten when I deploy to firebase again. I just tried it though, and it looks like that doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks!

Comment: That used to be the case a long while back, but that was fixed.