# Attach firebase cloud function or cache its data from cloud function call

Tags: firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a frontend component that consists of a chart and several different filters that allow users to filter by data type. However, the data that they are filtering is relatively large, and so I do not want to load all of it into the webpage, and instead have a firebase cloud function handle the filtering. The issue is that users will usually do a bunch of filtering while using this component, so it does not make sense for the cloud function to repeatedly download the necessary data. Is there a way to "attach" the cloud function to the call and have it update without having to re-retrieve the data, or to somehow cache the retrieved firebase data somewhere accessible to the cloud function if this is not possible?

```
exports.handleChartData = functions.database.ref("chartData").onCall((data, context) => {
    // can I cache data here somehow
    // or can I have this function read in updates from user selected filters
    // without having to retrieve data again?
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  But I will say that there is no effective "caching" in Cloud Functions.  You're better off using the client cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write data to the local `/tmp` disk. Just be aware that:

- There is no guarantee that the data will be there next time, as instances are spun up and down as needed. So you will need to check if the file exists on each call, and be ready to create it when it doesn't exist yet.
- The `/tmp` disk space is a RAM disk, so any files written there will come out of the memory you've allocated for your Cloud Functions containers.
- You can't reliably keep listeners alive across calls, so you won't be able to update the cache.

Also see:

- [Write temporary files from Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719793/write-temporary-files-from-google-cloud-function)
- the [documentation on cleaning up temporary files](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files)
- [Firebase cloud function [ Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.] on youtube video upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285089/firebase-cloud-function-error-memory-limit-exceeded-function-invocation-was)

Comment: Frank thanks for your reply. A couple of questions then:

1. Per your bullet point 1, would the same instance likely last a while, and serve requests sent from the front end (if it is using the same /tmp space)?
2. Couldn't you just use the etag parameter to check if the cache is stale, and then re-retrieve the data if it is?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. There are no guarantees whatsoever about the lifetime of an instance. 2. there isn't enough information to answer that. I'd say you give it a try, and if you get stuck, open a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).