# If I allocate my Cloud Function 256MB, does each of its function instance have access to 256MB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

If I create a Google Cloud Function and allocate it 256 MB, does this mean that every instance of this function that is created will have access to this much RAM, or does it mean that all function instances created will have to share these 256 MB ?

The latter would make little sense for a scalable product, but I get the feeling my functions run out of memory quite quickly for tasks that should not be so memory intensive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions don't run concurrently on a given instance. So let's say you have 2 requests coming at the same time, 2 instances will be spawned to handle those requests and each instance will have 256 MB. If a 3rd request comes in and one of the previous requests have finished, then Cloud Functions may reuse the running instance and route the request to it.

Your function may be making an improper use of global variables. Or you may be writing files to the `/tmp` folder which data written to the volume is [stored in memory as explained in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53285268/4926605) (you should then delete the file before each function ends). You may have a look at [Cloud Function Tips documentations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) for some optimization details.