# GCP functions understand instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-2nd-generation-now-generally-available) appears to use the term "instance" interchangeably

The instance (hardware) and the instance (software) are made to sound like they are the same but they are clearly not.

My question is more around the instance (hardware); do I get to specify the instance count (ie the server count ) ? When I create a function I only get to select the "memory allocated".

Answer (score 1):

A hardware instance is a physical server on which `Cloud Functions` will run. A software instance is a running copy of your function that is hosted on a hardware instance.

The memory allocated to a `Cloud Function` can be specified when the function is created. This memory is used to hold the function's code, runtime environment, and any data that the function needs to access.

You can specify the maximum or minimum hardware instance using `gcloud` while creating function as below

```
//to set maximum instance
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --max-instances MAX_INSTANCE_LIMIT

//to set minimum instance
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME \
--min-instances MIN_INSTANCE_LIMIT
```

Setting a minimum instance will reduce cold start.

If you want to use the console, In the Maximum, Minimum instances field in the Autoscaling section, input your desired value, or simply use the suggested default.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances#setting_and_clearing_maximum_instances_limits

Comment: Wow, thats interesting. I always thought "max-instances" referred to the software instance count. If "max-instances" refers to the hardware instance, do we get to specify the size of each instance in this command as well ?

Comment: @user1074593 If you are asking about memory, Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54266965/18265570)

Comment: No, I am just not convinced that "max-instances" refers to hardware. Sorry.

Comment: I don't think you can assign memory size for each instance. As cloud function is serverless, applications are deployed will be managed by google. Can you elaborate, why you were not convinced?